# PUT to update resource with partial data?

Tags: rest

Let's say that we already have a `Book` resource at `/books/123`. This `Book` has several properties, like: `isbn`, `year`, `title`.

PUT method is used to update *whole* resource. So if we want to update just the `title` we need to pass everything else, too.

PATCH can be used to update only some properties of the resource.

What should happens if we do PUT with partial data? For example, PUT with only `title` and `isbn`?

As I see, this should *replace* existing resource and no error should be signalized back. Right?

Comment: It should respond with a 400 bad request after validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking, *should*, then I would agree with you. It should replace the existing resource and no error would be signaled back. Of course, if the data is incomplete, e.g. you did `PUT` with only the `title`, and `isbn` is required, then you might get a `400` error back, whereas `PATCH` would be just fine with that.

However, many many (most? never surveyed) REST APIs do not follow it. About the only thing that I commonly see well-followed is that `GET /resource` is the list and `GET /resource/:resource` is a single resource. Many such APIs use `POST` for update, when `POST` is intended for create, etc.

So, if you are asking:

- Do APIs currently in place have `PUT` be strictly replace, the answer is no.
- If you are designing a new API, I would recommend sticking to what you outlined.